# linq comparing two lists of ids?

Tags: sql, linq

I have a list of longs.
I want to do a linq query to compare that the linq of longs equal to the list of ids in a table.
A pub has features, the features have ids, i want to select all pubs whose features are in this list of longs...

code:

`IList<long> pubFeatures` is passed into function.

```
var result = from pubs in result
              where pubs.PubFeatures.Select(item => item.Id).All(term => pubFeatures.Contains(term))
             select pubs;
```

But this doesnt seem to work it returns all pubs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = from pub in pubs
             where pub.PubFeatures.Select(item => pubFeatures.Contains(item.id))
             select pub
```

Comment: i get...Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool>' to 'bool'

Comment: because i think pubfeatures is a another table and cant compare entire row need to compare just the id of that row?

Comment: i used .Any instead of select, seems to like it better but still doesnt return correct result